# Entity Framework : Handling childern with DBSet<Parent>

Tags: entity-framework

I have a `Parent` class that has a `Child`, I am using TPH, and exposing only `DBSet<Parent>` in the `DBContext` . Now I would like to use the `Where(x = x.PropertyInChild)` on the `DBSet<Parent>` where `x` is a `Child`, casting `x` during the process reveals the following error.

> LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration
>   types.

Comment: can you post your parent and child classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implicitly include the derived entities in the OnModelCreating method.

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>();
    }
}
```

To query child entities you need to use **OfType< TEntity >** method.

```
var parents = context.Parents.OfType<Child>().ToList();
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it more dynamic? A way to make context.Parents auto detect the type and behave consequently?

Comment: @sisyphus what you mean by dynamic ??

Comment: I meant I should pass a casted x then the EF would dynamically detect its type and hence I don't have to use the OfType<Child> method.

Comment: You don't need to include the children in the parent - you can just use `context.Parents.OfType<Child>()....`